# Clone element when i start drag and drop it to my gridsystem

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have couple of divs that are representing my components.
This components i want to drag and drop to my Gridsystem.
But i need to clone them. SO they still in the Component menu so i can drag more of them.

```
    GRIDSYSTEM
    $('#GridDiv').droppable({
    accept: ".draaa",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        var offset = draggable.offset();

        draggable.appendTo( this ).offset( offset );
            draggable.resizable({
            // animate: true
            grid: 10,
            containment: "#GridDiv",
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var width = ui.size.width;
                var height = ui.size.height;
                $('#width').text('width: ' + ui.size.width);
                $('#height').text('height: ' + ui.size.height);
                },
            });
        }
    });

    DRAGCOMPONENTS
     $('.draaa').draggable({ 
    grid: [ 20, 20 ],
    drag: function(event, ui){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
       // $('#xFOR').text('x: ' + xPos);
       // $('#yFOR').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    start: function( event, ui ) {
    var ID = event.originalEvent.target.id;

    //$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
    //alert(event.originalEvent.target.id);
    //alert(typeof(ID));
    var original = $(ID);
    var newClone = original.clone();

    }

    });
```

I "think" i should do on start something in the draggle. Someone have any hint ? or idea ? i get the ID om element from 
     var ID = event.originalEvent.target.id;

Answer (score 5):

Just set [the helper option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) of draggable to `'clone'`. The element will be cloned and the clone will be dragged, see example below:

```js
$(function() {

$(".draggable").draggable({
 grid: [ 20, 20 ],
 appendTo: '#droppable',
    containment: "window",
 cursor: 'move',
 revertDuration: 100,
 revert: 'invalid',
 helper: 'clone'
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
 drop: function (event, ui) {
  ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#droppable');
    }
});


});
```

```css
.draggable { width: 90px; height: 80px; border: red 1px solid; }
#droppable { height: 140px; border: black 1px solid;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="droppable">
 <p>droppable</p>
</div>
<br style="clear:both">
<div id="storage">
 <div class="draggable">
  <p>draggable-1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="draggable">
  <p>draggable-2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="draggable">
  <p>draggable-3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can delete draggable div which is dropped.